# mysql- get number of occurrences

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sum, left-join

Hi i am trying to get a mysql query working and need some help. I have 2 tables (staff, booking).

Staff table contains staff details

| StaffID | First_name | Last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe |
| 2 | Mary | Doe |

Booking table contains

| BookingID | StaffID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | cancelled |
| 2 | 1 | cancelled |
| 3 | 1 | confirmed |
| 4 | 2 | cancelled |
| 5 | 1 | confirmed |

I would like to get the count of confirmed/cancelled bookings for each staff but is having trouble getting it to work. My current query that I'm using is

```
Select staff.StaffID, staff.First_name, staff.Last_name, sum(booking.Status LIKE '$status') as Status 
from staff, booking 
where staff.StaffID = booking.ConvenerID 
group by staff.StaffID
```

`$status` being `cancelled` or `confirmed`. With this query I'm only able to display a row if there is a status value, if a staff have no cancelled it does not display the row for that staff. How can I get the row to display even if the count of `$status` is `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join of the tables:

```
SELECT s.StaffID, s.First_name, s.Last_name, 
       COALESCE(SUM(b.Status = ?), 0) AS counter 
FROM staff s LEFT JOIN booking b
ON s.StaffID = b.StaffID 
GROUP BY s.StaffID;
```

Replace `?` with the status value that you want (there is no reason to use the operator `LIKE` because a simple `=` works fine).